# Closure recursion and retain cycles

Tags: ios, swift

My closure retains itself. It causes capturing all other objects inside. I can pass such objects using weak reference, but it doesn't solve the problem of retain cycle. What's the right way to do recursion with closures without retain cycles?

```
class Foo {
  var s = "Bar"
  deinit {
    print("deinit") // Won't be executed!
  }
}

class TestVC: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let foo = Foo() // Weak works, but not the right solution.
    var closure: () -> Void = { return }
    closure = {
      print(foo.s)
      if true {
        return
      } else {
        closure()
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: @matt I've changed the code. Deinit will be called only if foo is weak. But it doesn't solve closure retain cycle problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an unusual setup where your closure retains itself. Note that Swift doesn't allow you to create a weak reference to a closure.

To break the retain cycle, set `closure` to `{ }` in the base case of the recursion. Here's a test macOS command-line program:

```
func test() {
    var closure: ((Int) -> ()) = { _ in }
    closure = { i in
        if i < 10 {
            closure(i + 1)
        } else {
            // Comment out this line for unbounded memory consumption.
            closure = { _ in }
        }
    }
    closure(0)
}

while true {
    test()
}
```

If you run this, its memory consumption is flat.

If you comment out the line in the base case that resets `closure`, its memory consumption grows without bound.

Comment: And yet a closure is a reference type, so a weak ref seems possible and desirable. See for example https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8205

Comment: `closure = { _ in }` helped in my case! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `closure` is holding `foo` instance reference.
`foo` will be released as soon as the `closure` is released.

`closure` is calling itself. If we pass weak `self` inside `closure` then that should be fine. OR by resetting `closure`

below code should work fine.

```
var closure: () -> Void = { return }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let foo = Foo()

    closure = { [weak self] in
        print(foo.s)
        if true {
            return
        } else {
            self?.closure()
        }
    }
}
```

OR initialize `foo` inside `closure`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var closure: () -> Void = { return }
    closure = { [weak self] in
        let foo = Foo()
        print(foo.s)
        if true {
            return
        } else {
            self?.closure()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, it won't. I've changed the code above to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your closure into [a nested function](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID178):

```
class Foo {
  var s = "Bar"
  deinit {
    print("deinit")
  }
}

class TestVC: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let foo = Foo()
    func nestedFunction() {
      print(foo.s)
      if true {
        return
      } else {
        nestedFunction()
      }
    }
    nestedFunction()
  }

}
```

In Swift nested functions can refer to themselves synchronously (recursive functions) or asynchronously (typically for asynchronous iteration), can do so without any reference cycle, and can capture variables just as well as closures do. You can even have mutually recursive nested functions.

You *could* instead reset the closure-containing variable to a dummy closure once done, I am not saying this does not work, but this is very error-prone, especially when the closure calls itself asynchronously: the reset has to be done asynchronously as well in that case. Better have the lack of a reference cycle be ensured statically, as can be done most everywhere else in Swift.

(The concept used to have a bad rap due to an implementation in the C language by gcc that introduced security holes as a result of attempting to squeeze a closure reference into a C function pointer i.e. a code address, but Swift nested functions have nothing to do with that)